# Dismiss a UIViewController and make ui change in another class

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa, uiviewcontroller

In my app I have 2 classes of `UIViewController`. The `FirstViewController` is a view that has this method,that adds a uitableview to the view of the controller:

```
 -(IBAction)SetTabState:(id)sender{
    if (sender == History) {
            [self.view  addSubview:HistoryView];
    }
}
```

Now, in `SecondViewController` class I have 2 options to navigate back.
The first option of navigating back is simply to go back which works fine :

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

The second option to navigate back and to bring up the history of view from the SeconedViewController
So I am trying Something like this :

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
FirstViewController *Vc = [[FirstViewController alloc]init];
[Vc SetTabState:Vc.History];
```

The true is that firing a methods from `UIViewController` classes was something I have never understand.

Comment: Please elaborate your question. I think you want to do something like this. when you come to first view from second then you should present with tableview. Is it right or you want to do something else?

Comment: yes but only when i am returning from the second view controller with this specific request

Comment: am still not sure about your requirement, but i feel delegates and protocols is what you are looking for.

Comment: I don't know what you do exactly in SetTabState function. but if i am not wrong then you have to do just simple think, when you enter into first controller by specific event then just bring you tableview to front or set it again. [self.view bringSubviewtoFront:self.tableView] something like this.

Comment: it's a simple call
defining a protocol for this simple action is to get it to complicated
and what i think i not right.

Comment: it will help, if you could post some code!!

Comment: i dont have something else to post. think of it like a simple app that shows a blank page on the first view controller and the is a code the add a tableview to the screen. the second view controller have 2 buttuns the first is dismiss the view controller to the first view controller that is currently blank, and the second one do the same dismiss thing but also call the method that shows the tableview. thats it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the information prior to dismissing the modal. Something like this:

```
SecondViewController.m:
- (IBAction) secondButtonTouched:(UIButton)button {
  FirstViewController *fVC = (FirstViewController *)self.presentingViewController;
  [fVC SetTabState:History];
  [fVC dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

You need to get the reference to the existing `FirstViewController`, not create a new one.

NOTE: You should pass a weak reference (or delegate/protocol) for SecondVC to have the reference to FirstVC instead of assuming that the `presentingViewController` is of type `FirstViewController`. I did that to simplify my code.